# Ask only for Mic permission Opentok

Tags: javascript, reactjs, permissions, opentok

I'm using OpenTok RTC. And I need to only grant permission for Mic only.

I have been reading the documentations and I'm using the getDevices which asks for camera and mic permissions. And I only need Mic permission

I can't find a way around this yet

Link for getDevices [here](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#getDevices)

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok RTC provides two methods for granting permissions for microphone access. The first is using the JavaScript API when you create the session. You can set the media mode to "audio-only" which will only grant access to the microphone. The second is using the Android/iOS SDK. When the session is created, you can set the AudioTrackConstraints to "AudioTrackConstraints.audioOnly()" which will also only grant access to the microphone.

Comment: Thank you but I need it before creating a session, to test the quality of the audioDevice using opentok-network-test, specifically when initializing a publisher

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might encounter this, set videoSource to false when initializing a publisher.

link for reference https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher